# React Native Run Task Once a Day

Tags: ios, react-native, background-process

I want the badge of my app to display the number of events a user has planned for today. With my current solution, the badge count only updates when the user opens the app, so it is very impractical. I am looking for the best way to update this number in the background.

My current options are:

1. Run a background fetch task, which periodically checks the number of events and updates the badge - from the documentation of [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch), it looks like this won't work on iOS if the app is terminated.
2. Send periodic push notifications from a server to every user, setting the badge count for them - I would have to send this notification much more frequently than once a day because of different timezones.

Which approach would be better? Or is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the second approach is because of following points

- there is a good chance that if you app is not opened frequently on IOS then the IOS will stop running you background task.
- Also Many operating system shuts down background processing in battery saver modes.

So i think using notification to trigger a task is a better option.